# XSL check if multiple elements of same name and attribute is equal to a given text

Tags: xslt

I'm writing this XSLT file and having issue on how to do the following. I have a list of elements with the same name attribute and I need to copy them over and check if they have the text Required. If none of the elements do not add a element that does.

Example XML:

```
<record>
  </Title>
  </subTitle>
  <note tag='1'>
    <access tag='1'>nothing</access>
    <access tag='a'>Home</access>
    <access tag='a'>School</access>
  </note tag='1'>
</record>
```

With that example It would output:

```
<record>
  </Title>
  </subTitle>
  <note tag='1'>
    <access tag='1'>nothing</access>
    <access tag='a'>Home</access>
    <access tag='a'>School</access>
    <access tag="a'>Required</access>
  </note tag='1'>
</record>
```

If the resulting xml was ran through the xslt again it would output as is with no changes. I know how to do this if access with attribute a would only ever be 1 element. The issues I have is checking multiple.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

**Here is a short and simple solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
 "note[not(access[@tag = 'a' and . = 'Required'])]">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
   <access tag="a">Required</access>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied to the provided XML document** (corrected the severely malformed original to a well-formed XML document):

```
<record>
    <Title/>
    <subTitle/>
    <note tag='1'>
        <access tag='1'>nothing</access>
        <access tag='a'>Home</access>
        <access tag='a'>School</access>
    </note>
</record>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<record>
   <Title/>
   <subTitle/>
   <note tag="1">
      <access tag="1">nothing</access>
      <access tag="a">Home</access>
      <access tag="a">School</access>
      <access tag="a">Required</access>
   </note>
</record>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="note[count(access[text()='Required'])=0]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        <xsl:element name="access">
        <xsl:attribute name="tag">a</xsl:attribute>
        Required
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: thanks for the help. Use of count helps. What about taking into account the attribute of a. IE if tag='1' has Required in it then I still want to add it.